# Clarification on ending a while loop

Tags: while-loop

I am currently working with a while loop and was confused as to why I couldn't end the loop.

I played around with it for a little while and for some reason the following code works and ends the while loop:

```
boolean keepGoing = true;       
while (keepGoing != false)
   {
     //execute code
   }
   System.out.println("Would you like to continue? Enter Y for yes or N for no.");
   String keepGoingYesOrNo = input.nextLine();
   if (keepGoingYesOrNo.equals("Y"))
      {
        keepGoing = true;
        matchCount=0;
        guessCount=0;
      }
   else 
      {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        keepGoing = false;
```

But the alternative doesn't end the while loop:

```
boolean keepGoing = true;       
while (keepGoing = true)
   {
     //execute code
   }
   System.out.println("Would you like to continue? Enter Y for yes or N for no.");
   String keepGoingYesOrNo = input.nextLine();
   if (keepGoingYesOrNo.equals("Y"))
      {
        keepGoing = true;
        matchCount=0;
        guessCount=0;
      }
   else 
      {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        keepGoing = false;
```

Shouldn't **while (keepGoing = true)** and **while (keepGoing != false)** be the same thing. I got the code to work but I was hoping to get some clarification on why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Shouldn't setting keepGoing = false end both while loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to look out for is that (keepGoing = true) and **(keepGoing == true)** are not the same. If you want to check if keepGoing is true, you should use ==. When you use the single =, you're *assigning* true to keepGoing, so every time you're trying to check if it's true, you're actually *setting* it to true.

Also, because while loops are already checking if the condition is true, you could simplify your while statement to just **while (keepGoing) {}**.